# Otorgar valor byte en un set

Tags: java, hibernate, base-de-datos, hql

Tenemos una DB con un tabla Usuario que tiene una column de tipo Tinyint (Puesto que es un boolean) y estamos trabajando con Hibernate. Mi modelo Usuario tiene una variable, autogenerada, tipo Byte para designar ese valor de usuario (setters & getters).

El caso es que dentro de este método:

```
    public boolean CreateJudge(int idusuario){
    boolean newJ = false;

    try{
        newJ = true;
        this.session = Hibernate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Usuario newJudge = new Usuario(master.setJuez((byte) 1), idusuario);
        session.save(newJudge);
        session.close();

    }catch (Exception e){ 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }     
    return newJ;
}
```

Lo que quiero es poder darle ese valor 1 al byte y así forzar a que ese usuario sea un juez.

¿Alguna idea? El código planteado no funciona y ya he probado:

```
   Usuario newJudge = new Usuario(master.setJuez(1), idusuario);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tras una rato dándole vueltas he encontrado yo mismo la solución a mi problema (algo muy básico):

```
    public boolean CreateJudge(){
    boolean newJ = false;

    try{
        newJ = true;
        Byte juez = 1;
        this.session = Hibernate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Usuario newJudge = new Usuario(master.getDni(), master.getTelefono(), master.getNickname(), master.getPassword(), master.getEmail(), master.getAdmin(), juez);
        session.save(newJudge);
        session.close();

    }catch (Exception e){ 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }     
    return newJ;
}
```

Generamos un nuevo usuario en este caso: newJudge; y forzamos un Byte juz = 1, al saber que siempre que invoquemos al método CreateJudge(); lo que estamos haciendo es crear un usuario que es juez.

Añado:

Por si alguien quisiera una forma de hacer update a un objeto Usuario ya existente dentro de la DB, tendría simplemente que hacer lo siguiente:

```
      public boolean UpdateToJudge(int nickname){
    boolean upUj = false;       
    this.session = Hibernate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    try{
        upUj = true;
        Usuario improve;
        Query update = session.createQuery("from Usuario as usser where usser.nickname='"+nickname+"'");
        improve = (Usuario)update.uniqueResult();
        improve.setJuez((byte) 1);
        session.saveOrUpdate(improve);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        tx.rollback();
    }
    return upUj;
}
```

Como se puede ver, extraemos el objeto de la base de datos, lo guardamos de forma temporal en nuestro método y le cambiamos el value de Juez a 1, consiguiendo así el update.